# How to use SQL PARTITION BY GROUPS?

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I'm working with PostgreSQL 12, but the question is standard SQL.
I have a table like this:

```
| timestamp                | raw_value |
| ------------------------ | --------- |
| 2015-06-27T03:52:50.000Z | 0         |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:00.000Z | 0         |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:10.000Z | 1         |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:20.000Z | 1         |
| 2015-06-27T04:22:20.000Z | 1         |
| 2015-06-27T04:22:30.000Z | 0         |
| 2015-06-27T05:33:40.000Z | 1         |
| 2015-06-27T05:33:50.000Z | 1         |
```

I need to get the first and last timestamp of each group with raw_value = 1, i.e. **needed result** :

```
| start_time               | end_time                 |
| ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:10.000Z | 2015-06-27T04:22:20.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T05:33:40.000Z | 2015-06-27T05:33:50.000Z |
```

My best effort so far looks like this:

```
SELECT timestamp, raw_value, row_number() over w as rn, first_value(obt) OVER w AS start_time, last_value(obt) OVER w AS end_time
FROM mytable
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY raw_value ORDER BY timestamp GROUPS CURRENT ROW )
ORDER BY timestamp;
```

Google doesn't have much info about it, but according to the [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS) the "GROUPS" clause is exactly what I need, but the end result is wrong, because window functions simply copy value from the timestamp column:

```
| timestamp                | raw_value | rn  | start_time               | end_time                 |
| ------------------------ | --------- | --- | ------------------------ | ------------------------ |
| 2015-06-27T03:52:50.000Z | 0         | 1   | 2015-06-27T03:52:50.000Z | 2015-06-27T03:52:50.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:00.000Z | 0         | 2   | 2015-06-27T03:53:00.000Z | 2015-06-27T03:53:00.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:10.000Z | 1         | 1   | 2015-06-27T03:53:10.000Z | 2015-06-27T03:53:10.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T03:53:20.000Z | 1         | 2   | 2015-06-27T03:53:20.000Z | 2015-06-27T03:53:20.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T04:22:20.000Z | 1         | 3   | 2015-06-27T04:22:20.000Z | 2015-06-27T04:22:20.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T04:22:30.000Z | 0         | 3   | 2015-06-27T04:22:30.000Z | 2015-06-27T04:22:30.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T05:33:40.000Z | 1         | 4   | 2015-06-27T05:33:40.000Z | 2015-06-27T05:33:40.000Z |
| 2015-06-27T05:33:50.000Z | 1         | 5   | 2015-06-27T05:33:50.000Z | 2015-06-27T05:33:50.000Z |
```

At line#6 I'd expect the row number to reset to 1, but it doesn't! I tried using `BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING` as well without luck.

I have created a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/JRS6jKB2Ni1toxtHeASfc/0) link for your convenience as well.

If there is any other way to achieve the same result in SQL (ok to be PG-specific) without window functions, I'd like to know.

Comment: `PARTITION BY raw_value` will bundle *all* rows with the same `raw_value`, regardless if there are rows with a different `raw_value` between them or not. This is a "gaps and islands" problem; search for that keyword.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Identify groups using `row_number() - sum()` [trick](https://blog.jooq.org/2015/11/07/how-to-find-the-longest-consecutive-series-of-events-in-sql/), then choose min and max time for each identified group.

```sql
with grp as (
  select obt, raw_value
       , row_number() over w - sum(raw_value) over w as g
  from tm_series
  window w as (order by obt)
)
select min(obt), max(obt)
from grp
where raw_value = 1
group by g;
```

DB fiddle [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/JRS6jKB2Ni1toxtHeASfc/0).

(The `GROUPS` clause depends on window ordering and seems to have nothing common with your problem.)

Answer (score 2):

Your [updated fiddle here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/JRS6jKB2Ni1toxtHeASfc/1).

For an gaps and islands approach, first mark your transitions from `raw_value = 0` to `raw_value = 1`

```
with mark_changes as (
  select obt, raw_value,
         case
           when raw_value = 0 then 0
           when raw_value = lag(raw_value) over (order by obt) then 0
           else 1
         end as transition
    from tm_series
),
```

Keep only the `raw_value = 1` rows, and `sum()` the preceding `transition` markers to place each row into a group.

```
id_groups as (
  select obt, raw_value, 
         sum(transition) over (order by obt) as grp_num
    from mark_changes
   where raw_value = 1
)
```

Use `group by` on these `grp_num` values to get your desired result.

```
select min(obt) as start_time, 
       max(obt) as end_time
  from id_groups
 group by grp_num
 order by min(obt);
```